# Turkish Character Query in Asp.net Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, oracle10g, locale, turkish

I have a asp.net web forms application that query data in oracle 10g. In the target table, NAMESURNAME column exists, it contains NAME + " " + SURNAME structure. I have two different queries below:

Query 1:

```
select 
    NAMESURNAME, PERSONELID 
from 
    personeliliski2015 t 
where 
    nls_upper(t.NAMESURNAME, 'NLS_SORT = XTURKISH') like nls_upper('%OSMAN%', 'NAMESURNAME = XTURKISH')
```

Query 2:

```
select 
    NAMESURNAME, PERSONELID 
from 
    personeliliski2015 t 
where 
    nls_upper(t.NAMESURNAME, 'NLS_SORT = XTURKISH') like nls_upper('%SÖZGEN%', 'NAMESURNAME = XTURKISH')
```

If you notice that query 2 contains Turkish character, 'Ö'.

Here is the function of asp.net web forms application:

```
public void VeriGetir(DataTable dt, string sOracle)
{
    OracleDataAdapter da = null;

    try
    {

        dt.Clear();
        da = new OracleDataAdapter(sOracle, cn);
        OpenConnection();

        if (IsTransactional)
            da.SelectCommand.Transaction = tr;

        da.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw HataOlustur(e, sOracle);
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

Query 1 returns many result, (as expected) however query 2 does not return any result. However there are many records that NAMESURNAME contains "SÖZGEN". What is wrong with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could it be sözgen rather than SÖZGEN? some characters can differ lower uppercase depend on your sql servers configuration.

Comment: I use same query in different database with same NLS_LANG settings, and it worked. NAMESURNAME is 'OSMAN SÖZGEN', it is uppercase in database.